# Django - Form Does Not Save User Values

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I currently have a form on the “myaccount.html” page of my web application.

This form renders how I want however I cannot submit the form values for some reason to appear in the django admin.

When a user hits “submit”, the page refreshes and the values stay in the input fields.

I’ve tried many methods to solve this but no luck. I thought I had everything together but maybe I’m missing something somewhere?

Is there anything I’m missing to resolve this issue?

I’m new to Django so any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

## users/views.py

```
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET, require_POST
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.conf import settings
from django import forms

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'signup.html'

class change(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('myaccount')
    template_name = 'myaccount.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.name = self.request.name
        form.instance.address = self.request.address
        form.instance.zip_code = self.request.zip_code
        form.instance.mobile_number = self.request.mobile_number
        form.save()
        return super(change, self).form_valid(form)
```

## users/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        case_insensitive_username_field = '{}__iexact'.format(self.model.USERNAME_FIELD)
        return self.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field: username})


#class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
#    objects = CustomUserManager()

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # add additional fields in here
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

## users/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Full Name', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    address = forms.CharField(required=True, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address', 'class': 'form-control'}))    
    zip_code = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Zipcode', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    mobile_number = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Mobile Number', 'class': 'form-control'}))


    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number')
        help_texts = {
            'username': '',
            'email': '',
#            'password1': 'None',
#            'password2': 'Test'
        }


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

## users/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from . import views
from users import views
from .views import change

urlpatterns = [
#    path('change/', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='change'),
#    path('myaccount/change/', HomeView.as_view(), name='change'),
#    url(r'^myaccount/change/$', views.horse, name='change'),  
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('myaccount/', views.change.as_view(), name='myaccount'),

]
```

## users/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number']

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**HTML**

```
{% block content %}

<form role="form" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}   
{{ form.name }}
{{ form.name.errors }}
{{ form.address }}
{{ form.address.errors }}
{{ form.zip_code }}
{{ form.zip_code.errors }}
{{ form.mobile_number }}
{{ form.mobile_number.errors }}
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-success btn-round btn-extend" type="submit" value="Submit"><i class="zmdi zmdi-favorite-outline6"></i>Submit</button>
</form>                                                                                                                                         
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the fields or errors for the fields you inherit from the parent class. Without them the form will not be valid. Try adding `{{ form.errors }}` to see the full list of validation errors.

Comment: So i added that snippet as you suggested and now I see validation errors of fields I don't want in this specific page.`username`, `password1`, `password2` are the fields I don't want on this page. I have those set currently to signup.html.  How can I fix that?

Comment: If you don't want those fields, why are you inheriting from UserCreationForm?

Comment: Initially, I wanted to add additional fIelds to UserCreationForm since I'm making a User Profile page & thought that this issue wouldn't occur. I want users to change their username and email on the front end as well as I want all the form values to populate in the admin, what's the best way of doing that?

Comment: Issue resolved! I made a new form and added `class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number', ]` to `admin.py` and now my form data populates correctly... I just need to make sure information doesn't duplicate :)

Answer (score 1):

For your form_valid method try this instead:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save(commit=False) # object with form data
    user.save() # save object
    return redirect('success') # and then redirect to success view
```

Also for your template you can use a for loop to reduce code:

```
{% for field in form %}
 {{ field.label_tag }}
 {{ field }}
 {% if field.errors %}
    {{ field.errors }}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and no luck. I tried to redirect to the same page but not sure if this is correct? `return redirect('myaccount')`

Comment: What happened? Was anything saved? Try print (user) in the form_valid method and see what the output is in the console. Also, ideally you should redirect to another page and render a success message or something so that the user knows their registration was successful.

Comment: @spidey677 - forgot to notify you of comment above

Comment: Nothing was solved. I tried `print (name)` and there's no output in console. I'm very new to python/django.. what can the issue be my friend?

Comment: @spidey677 - try print (user.name)

Comment: Issue resolved! I made a new form & added `class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number', ]` to `admin.py` and now my form data populates correctly... I just need to make sure information doesn't duplicate :)